# Parse Two XML using Python

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing, automation, code-generation

I have an XML file that contains 200 **Event** blocks looking like below:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<ProjectData xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.project.com/proj1/projv" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.pp.com/oj/p http://www.onj.com/p/IXX/schema/proj.xsd">
  <fileType>This file is sample</fileType>
  <header>
    <fileID>none</fileID>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <modified>2015-09-16T17:03:25</modified>
  </header>
  <EventList>
    <Event>
      <Id>0</Id>
      <pp define="something">2</pp>
      <Index>3</Index>
      <Conf ref="point">CFG.AC.UF</Conf>
      <Check>tttt</Check>
      <Group>wwll</Group>
      <Heart ref="point">mbmb</Heart>
      <Name>kkk</Name>
      <Thresh ref="point">kckcv</Thresh>
      <Hyster ref="point">foo</Hyster>
      <Trip ref="point">dim</Trip>
      <Clear ref="point">CLR.AC.UF</Clear>
    </Event>
  </EventList>
</ProjData>
```

The **Event** block contains information that I am interested in taking (4 of them only: Id, Index, Name, and Group) to generate my new xml file. I want to do this by python code.
Does anyone know how I can achieve this by python.

My new xml file should look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Newevents>
   <event>
      <Id>0</Id>
      <Index>3</Index>
      <Name>kkk**$Id**</Name>
      <Group>wwll**$Index**</Group>
      <desc>placeholder</desc>
   </event>
</Newevents>
```

I also want to add the Id and Index which are numbers to name and group strings with three significant digit place holder. 
For example if the Id is 1, I want my Name be kkk001, or if Id is 3, I want my Name be kkk003.
Same for my group element string but using Index: if Index is 5 I want my group be wwll005.

I Googled but there are sporadic information about this.

1. Can anyone come up with a neat python code that do the parsing of my xml file and generate the new xml file in the format and numbering I want above?
2. I have another xml file called descXML.xml that I need to parse to only take the **desc** element string and add it to my **new** xml file. 
   In the second xml file that I have (descXML.xml), desc element data should be taken based on the **Id** match with my new xml file.
   Is there any possibility to do the check if **Id** element is equal to the **Id** element data of my new xml file, then add **desc** element content for the corresponding code number? How can I do this condition? Can you provide and example python for this?

Here is how descXML.xml file looks like and analogous to my first original xml file here are also 200 **Event** blocks:

```
<EventList>
  <Event>
    <Mnemonic>AC.UF.SLOW</Mnemonic>
    <Id define="xyz">3</Id>
    <Index>13</Index>
    <Description>today was warm and I want to go swimming</Description>
  </Event>
<EventList>
```

Can 1 and 2 above merge into one python file?

The final XML file I want should look like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Newevents>
   <event>
      <Id>3</Id>
      <Index>13</Index>
      <Name>kkk000</Name>
      <Group>wwll003</Group>
      <desc>today was warm and I want to go swimming</desc>
   </event>
```

Trial based on comments given below:

I tried to be consise here and try solution provided below but did not work so I am providing my exact xml files:

**My file1.xml**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<Dataizx xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.kklk.com/cx1/ASD" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.kklk.com/cx1/ASD http://www.kklk.com/cx1/ASD/schema/tell.xsd">
  <fileType>Auto-Generated IXX Events Metadata</fileType>
  <header>
    <fileID>none</fileID>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <modified>2015-09-16T17:03:25</modified>
  </header>
  <EventList>
    <Event>
      <Mnemonic>ijk</Mnemonic>
      <Id define="rece">2</Id>
      <Index>0</Index>
      <Config ref="point">shine</Config>
    </Event>
    <Event>
      <Mnem>xyz</Mnem>
      <Id define="teller">3</Id>
      <Index>1</Index>
      <Config ref="point">good</Config>
    </Event>
  </EventList>
</Dataizx>
```

**And here is my xml that contains the description:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<IXXData xmlns="http://www.mnm.com/mnm/mnm" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:i="http://www.mnm.com/mnm/mnm" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.mnm.com/mnm/mnm http://www.mnm.com/mnm/mnm/schema/mnm.xsd">
    <fileType>Merged IXX Events Metadata</fileType>
    <header>
        <fileID>none</fileID>
        <version>1.0 + none</version>
        <description>Merged event metadata.</description>
    </header>
    <EventList>
        <Event>
            <Id define="mmm">2</Id>
            <Description>everything was good.</Description>
        </Event>
        <Event>
            <Id define="lll">4</Id>
            <Description>teller and the other one.</Description>
        </Event>
        <Event>
            <Id define="ggg">3</Id>
            <Description>weather is nice.</Description>
        </Event>
    </EventList>
</IXXData>
```

I used your xsl and python but I could not get description out of the second file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider an XLST solution which can pick various nodes from original XML and merge nodes in an external XML based on specific criteria. Python (like many object-oriented programming languages) maintains an [XSLT processor](http://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html) like in its lxml module.

As information, [XSLT](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/) is a special-purpose, declarative programming language (not an object-oriented one) to transform XML files in various formats and structures.

Additionally for your purposes you can use XSLT's `document()` and `concat()` functions. Your XSLT was a little involved as it required setting a variable to match ids across documents and had quite a bit of namespaces to manage.

**XSLT** (save externally as .xsl file)

```
<xsl:transform version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xmlns:p="http://www.kklk.com/cx1/ASD"
 xmlns:i="http://www.sesolar.com/SE1/ICB"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.kklk.com/cx1/ASD http://www.kklk.com/cx1/ASD/schema/tell.xsd"
 exclude-result-prefixes="xsi p i">

<xsl:output version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"/>

<xsl:template match="p:EventList">
    <NewsEvents>        
        <xsl:for-each select="p:Event">            
            <Id><xsl:value-of select="p:Id"/></Id>
            <Index><xsl:value-of select="p:Index"/></Index>
            <Name><xsl:value-of select="concat(p:Name, '00', p:Id)"/></Name>
            <Group><xsl:value-of select="concat(p:Group, '00', p:Index)"/></Group>
            <xsl:variable name="descID" select="p:Id"/>
            <desc><xsl:value-of select="document('descXML.xml')/i:IcbData/i:EventList/
                  i:Event/i:Id[text()=$descID]/following-sibling::i:Description"/></desc>            
        </xsl:for-each>
    </NewsEvents>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

**Python** (loads .xml and .xsl, transforming former with the latter for new .xml output)

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import lxml.etree as ET

dom = ET.parse('C:\\Path\\To\\MainXML.xml')
xslt = ET.parse('C:\\Path\\To\\AboveXSLT.xsl')
transform = ET.XSLT(xslt)
newdom = transform(dom)

tree_out = ET.tostring(newdom, encoding='UTF-8', pretty_print=True, xml_declaration=True)

xmlfile = open('C:\\Path\\To\\Output.xml','wb')
xmlfile.write(tree_out)
xmlfile.close()
```

**Output** (using above posted XML data)

(if descXML's Id matches any Event's Id, corresponding `<desc>` node below will be populated)

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<Dataroot>
  <NewsEvents>
    <Id>2</Id>
    <Index>0</Index>
    <Name>002</Name>
    <Group>000</Group>
    <desc>everything was good.</desc>
  </NewsEvents>
  <NewsEvents>
    <Id>3</Id>
    <Index>1</Index>
    <Name>003</Name>
    <Group>001</Group>
    <desc>weather is nice.</desc>
  </NewsEvents>
</Dataroot>
```

I know this XSLT approach may look intimidating but it saves much looping and creating elements, subelements, and attributes in Python code. I often recommend this route whenever XML files are being handled and I do find it ignored among programmers not just Pythoners. Meanwhile, most easily work with another special-purpose, declarative language without question -*SQL*!

Comment: Thank you.But why the description field is not being filled? Is the logic in xsl for description correct?

Comment: I think the reason that decription is empty all the time is because we are not searching the whole descXML.xml file. This file is my second xml file that has the description for each Event block, but since Events in this xml file are not in order, it is going to fill nothing in my final output! Is this true? Or there could be a another reason?

Comment: Ids in your posted XML content do not match. In descXML Id = 3 and in Event XML Id=0. Also, order does not matter, XSLT runs a `for-each` loop on every Event node and each time matches to descXML's Id.

Comment: Your solution is helpful but I think I am missing something here. I am posting my two xml files above and this time I have the Ids correct. Originally as I mentioned I had 200 Event blocks and I was expecting a match for description for a few.

Comment: Can you try my second trial and let me know if you get the result? I have two Ids matching. Please look at the section for ``Trial based on comments given below:''

Comment: See update. One challenge with your files is specifying the namespaces. Notice the `p` and `i` prefixes.